# What is the Difference Between yWriter5 and Scrivener?

Tags: technique, scrivener

I see that a lot of people like Scrivener better than yWriter. I know Scrivener is better, but my dad refuses to buy it, and I don't have a credit card. So, what does make Scrivener better than yWriter5?

Comment: You might change that to: "I believe that Scrivener will work better for me," rather than the blanket statement that it is better in general.  Obviously it's not better for you at the moment because it costs too much.   yWriter is free to download and use, and Scrivener has a free trial - download them both and decide for yourself if you really need Scrivener or if yWriter will work fine.  Then if you still want Scrivener, maybe you can persuade the Aged P's to give you an early Christmas present in time for NanoWrimo.

Comment: There are other alternatives to Scivener apart from yWriter.  Check out [bibisco](http://www.bibisco.com/), [Manuskript](http://www.theologeek.ch/manuskript/), [oStorybook](http://ostorybook.tuxfamily.org/?lng=en) and [Plume Creator](http://plume-creator.eu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a Mac, you can't use yWriter. :) Beyond that, from the screenshots it looks like yWriter only allows you to break into chapters, while Scrivener lets you have files in folders with no restraints on organization, as deep as you like, plus photos and audio files.

Scrivener has many tools, like Word Count Goals, frequency analysis, a name generator, a compiler, and the ability to do snapshots of your work so you can roll back to a previous draft. It's simply a more expansive, powerful program.

If you just need to get underway (and you're on a compatible platform), start with yWriter and save your money until you can get Scrivener. You can write in Notepad if you need to; you don't have to have Word.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for another writing software, Zoho Writer is a great option. It can hold a lot of words without getting too glitchy, and it's completely free! You can see word count, spelling/grammatical errors, leave comments, and share with others/collaborate.
(P.S. I know this was asked four years ago, but if you are still active on this site, I hope this is helpful!)

Comment: Questions are answers on Stack Exchange are intended to help anyone who has the same question, not just the person who actually asked. In most cases, it doesn't matter how old the question is, or whether the original asker is still active or not; if you're bringing something new to the table (which you are), then your answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Scrivener is now also available for iOS (the $19.99 app which is compatible with both Mac and Win desktop applications and allows you to sync the files over Dropbox), the features are subset, but still very useful.